# Deployment of one .net page from a test to live server

Tags: asp.net

I have been using .net for a couple of years. Whenever I publish a web site (to a test server or live server on our network) I always tick 'Allow this precompiled site to be updateable' and 'Use fixed naming and single page assemblies'.

Looking at the files produced on the test server after publishing - I can see, for example, a page called CustomerDetails.aspx and, in the bin folder, a file called App_Web_CustomerDetails.aspx.abcde7c2.dll

The files on the live server have exactly the same names.

I normally publish the whole site but I have a situation now with a hard to find bug that means I want to just update one page on the live server. After publishing a bug fix to the test server that seems to work, can I simply copy that page and its dll from the test server to the live server? Will that single page simply work on the live server or does it have to published with the context of the whole site?

Sorry to ask such a daft question, but I find the documentation on this on Microsoft's site not very clear.

Comment: Some additional documentation on 'xcopy deployments' from the Microsoft website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f735abw9(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, I'm pretty sure the answer is yes. Just copy the page, and the assemblies needed (and if it is dependent on any other updated assemblies). Take a look at the date modified as a hint of what to upload as well.

Granted, there's always a chance this could go wrong. So make sure you backup what you need to in the event something goes wrong (probably a good idea no matter what)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Before I publish to our live server, I always copy the entire 'publish' directory on the server. If I publish the web site and something goes wrong - I have always planned to simply copy the whole contents of the copy of the 'Publish_Copy' directory back into the 'Publish' directory and, hopefully, simply take the web site back to how it was before publishing. Never had to do it yet - touch wood. Will what I have described above work?

Comment: @MartinSmellworse That seems like it would work. If you've got the entire application bin folder and all, you should be able to restore it without issue. Certainly hope you never have to do that.